# Handling getting slow internet in android application programmatically

Tags: java, android

I am developing android an application fetching data from web server. I am usually able to fetch data from server using high-speed Wifi and 3G; however, 2G is very slow compare to 3G and Wifi. Is it possible to programmatically work around slow internet, such as if there is no 3G/Wifi access, and if not, is there anything I can do about it?

I ask because my application is supposed to fetch data from a server, even when speed drops to 2G levels, and I'm not very certain what to do if 3G/Wifi becomes slow or isn't available.

Comment: can you compress your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If faster internet was available, you'd be using it.  You can't speed up the internet with software-  its a matter of what networks are available and how much bandwidth they have-  basically up to your provider.  You could detect it and perhaps put off some long lasting downloads, but if you can't just decide to do it later you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

There is `ConnectivityManager` (look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html)) class in `Android Framework`. You can get this using:

```
Context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE).
```

You can get information about all supported network connection by the device using `public NetworkInfo[] getAllNetworkInfo ()` function ([more info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getAllNetworkInfo%28%29)). Then you can check all of it and make decision about network connection by your preference.

Also you can use `public NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo (int networkType)` method to get info about concrete network connection.